# I am unable to run jmeter on my cent os machine

Tags: java, linux, centos, jmeter

I tried to setup jmeter on my cent OS system, I had successfully copied and extracted the zip but when I am trying to open it through the command -

```
./jmeter.sh
```

it is showing the error like-

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set
```

then I had reffered some documents on internet and using that I had set my display variable using the command-

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

but still my issue in not solved. Please help me in solving the issue..

Comment: If it's a remote server, you need to pipe the X11 to your own computer. The server is headless (doesn't have a Graphical environment), so it can't create any windows or frames to display anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you need something called tightvnc server to see the graphical part of JMeter on your server machine.

The way that it works is you need a client to see the graphical interface.

http://www.tightvnc.com/

https://serverfault.com/questions/15882/is-it-possible-to-start-a-vnc-server-in-ubuntu-in-display-0-without-using-the-de